# Method for displaying binary number [C]

Tags: c

Not sure why, but the number being outputted is:

```
101101
```

Instead of

```
1011010
```

Any ideas why?

Here's my code:

```
typedef unsigned short bitSet;

int main() {
    bitSet bits = makeBitSet();
    displayBitSet(bits);
}

bitSet makeBitSet() {
    bitSet bits = 90;
    return bits;
}

displayBitSet(bitSet bs) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%d", ((bs & (int)pow(2, (16-1))) >> (16-i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: That should always print 16 digits, but `101101` is only 6 digits, and you were expecting it to print 7 - why?

Comment: Because 90 in binary is: 1011010

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WnrNhCiwvxIYX0UF): I got `0000000000000000` as output.

Comment: @Dongbae Your loop always prints 16 digits. 1011010 is not 16 digits.

Comment: Was `(16-1)` was mean to be `(16-i)`?

Comment: same for me on ideone 0000000000000000

Comment: chux comment makes it - 0000000000101101, which is still wrong, but closer (45)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resursion is useful to print binary digits while suppressing leading zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned short bitSet;

bitSet makeBitSet(void);
void displayBitSet(bitSet bs) ;

int main(void) {
    bitSet bits = makeBitSet();
    displayBitSet(bits);
    return 0;
}

bitSet makeBitSet(void) {
    bitSet bits = 90;
    return bits;
}

void displayBitSet(bitSet bs) {
    bitSet bsNext = bs >> 1;
    if (bsNext) displayBitSet(bsNext);
    printf("%d", bs & 1);
}
```

To specify the minimum number of digit to print, you can do so like this:

```
void displayBitSet2(bitSet bs, int minDigit) {
    bitSet bsNext = bs >> 1;
    int minDigitNext = (minDigit > 0 ? minDigit - 1 : 0);
    if (bsNext || minDigit > 1) displayBitSet2(bsNext, minDigitNext);
    printf("%d", bs & 1);
}
```

example: `displayBitSet2(0x90, 16);` to print at least 16 digits.

Comment: But what if I wanted those extra 0s in there? Better to have two results than one. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
void displayBitSet(bitSet bs) {
    for(int i = 15; i >= 0; --i)
        printf("%d", (bs >> i) & 1);
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using a floating point `pow` function for this. Maybe I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

90=64+0+16+8+0+0+2+0
    1 0  1 1 0 0 1 0

The answer you are expecting is 9 binary,followed by 10 binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to display 16 bits, using pow is not necessary like @Clark Gaebel said.
 If you are looking for a reference, have a look at below link.
The link contains both using printf and string/char*

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-convert-decimal-to-binary

Answer (score 0):

I have a clumsy but visualized method to solve "Method for displaying binary number" for a number of 16 bits. And 32 bits is alike.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned short b0 : 1, b1 : 1, b2 : 1, b3 : 1, b4 : 1, b5 : 1, b6 : 1, b7 : 1, b8 : 1, b9 : 1, b10 : 1, b11 : 1, b12 : 1, b13 : 1, b14 : 1, b15 : 1;
}stBit;

_Bool isBigEndian() {
    union {
        unsigned short a;
        unsigned char b[2];
    }n;
    n.a = 0xFF00;
    return n.b[0] == 0xFF;
}

void printStBit(stBit s) {
    if (isBigEndian()) {
        printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n", s.b0, s.b1, s.b2, s.b3, s.b4, s.b5, s.b6, s.b7, s.b8, s.b9, s.b10, s.b11, s.b12, s.b13, s.b14, s.b15);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n", s.b8, s.b9, s.b10, s.b11, s.b12, s.b13, s.b14, s.b15, s.b0, s.b1, s.b2, s.b3, s.b4, s.b5, s.b6, s.b7);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned short n = 90;
    stBit  s;
    memcpy(&s, &n, sizeof n);
    printStBit(s);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the result is [image]